# Order by after group by in 2 innerjoin

Tags: mysql

I have an issue that is showing wrong.

I am trying do the query but it doesn't affect anything in my results
in MySQL.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
dominio.id as dominio_id,palavras.id AS palavras_id,
palavras.palavra as palavras_palavra,rank_monitor.dominio as
rank_dominio,dominio.dominio AS dominio_dominio,
rank_monitor.palavras as rank_palavras,dominio.id as
id_dominio,rank_monitor.posicao_google as google,
rank_monitor.verificado as verificao_robo

FROM rank_monitor

INNER JOIN dominio ON rank_monitor.dominio=dominio.id
INNER JOIN palavras ON rank_monitor.palavras=palavras.id where dominio.id = 1
GROUP BY rank_monitor.palavras
order BY rank_monitor.verificado DESC
```

Comment: What does not effect ? Provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/yz5cyrvkn/ this is the Result
 doing in display the oldest results

Comment: You have `order BY rank_monitor.verificado DESC` and its showing data in that order, so where is the issue ?

Comment: the adjustment is made only in the 3 results, and not the entire table. ie always changes the order of these three only.
for example, there is this same record but more again.
those that appear are old. is that the problem is in the group by?
I would like to change the order of the whole table to the results to be new.
sorry me for my poor English.

Comment: The group by will return only one row per `rank_monitor.palavras` , and also its not needed here since you are not using any aggregate function.

Comment: if i remove the group by of the result is right but repeat few rows
http://postimg.org/image/f8fm434vt/
how is better way for this?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output into the question.

Comment: i provide the data in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0da1a/1
this db help?

Comment: Yes and please post the expected result into the question.

Comment: if you see in postimg.org/image/f8fm434vt i did the remotion of the group by of query now repeat all keywords 3 times. is right.
when used the Group By the SQL take only the Old Results.
i wanna that show it the newest result.
the column robo_verificacao have all dates of same keywords why it have every consults every times.
i wanna only the newest result from all table but showing correctly with not repeat.
thank you for patiencea

Comment: Is this what you are looking at ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0da1a/6

Comment: dude, u r the master!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it could be done:

```
select
d.id as dominio_id,
p.id AS palavras_id,
p.palavra as palavras_palavra,
rm.dominio as rank_dominio,
d.dominio as dominio_dominio,
rm.palavras as rank_palavras,
d.id as id_dominio,
rm.posicao_google as google,
rm.verificado as verificao_robo
from rank_monitor rm
join dominio d on d.id = rm.dominio
join palavras p on p.id = rm.palavras
left join rank_monitor rm1 on rm1.dominio = rm.dominio and rm1.palavras = rm.palavras
and rm1.verificado > rm.verificado 
where 
rm1.id is null
and
d.id = 1 
group by rm.palavras
```